# Dismissing UIAlertView programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView with the following delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
```

But I have a problem. In that method, I do some logic and perform some lines of code which take a small amount of time. I would like to dismiss the alertView before I do all of this. I want to dismiss the alert view at the very top of that method. That way, when the user taps a button on the alertView, the app doesn't seem frozen for a second while the next lines of code are executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use the delegate method `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` instead—it gets called once the alert view’s been removed from the screen, which will at least conceal the lag your app’s having—or, better, use a background thread, e.g. with `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`, to handle whatever processing you need to do.

Answer (score 12):

To dismiss a alert programaticly do: 
`/* Your Processing Code Here */
[theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`
The [theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; will make the alert go away

Comment: doesn't work.  did you mean: `[theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`

Answer (score 2):

Use the other delegate method for **did**, instead of **will**:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

You should probably also execute the other lines of code you mention asynchronously, so as not to freeze the UI at all.